# How can I sum and then remove duplicate fields MySql?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this turns out to be duplicate but I am having a hard time finding the exact answer...

I have  table that contains 'email'(varchar) and 'clicks'(int).

The email field contains duplicate instances of email values.  I would like to remove the duplicates and keep just one instance but also sum all values found in 'clicks' for that given email instance and update the remaining record to reflect that.

I can use distinct and group by to get a view of the records I am after, its the sum and update part I am stumped with.

Thanks.

Comment: You said you can use `distinct` and `group by`. This is the right track. Can you show us the code you used where you tried these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `DISTINCT` here, but rather you can just group on each `email` value, taking the sum of clicks as you go along:

```
SELECT email, SUM(clicks) AS clickSum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY email
```

When you mentioned "remaining" record, you neglected to mention how the duplicate records ever got deleted.  It would be a bunch of work to selectively remove all but one duplicate record.  I might go about this by just inserting the above query into a new table, deleting the old table, and renaming the new one to the old one:

```
CREATE TABLE yourNewTable (`email` varchar(255), `clicks` int);
INSERT INTO yourNewTable (`email`, `clicks`)
SELECT email, SUM(clicks)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY email

DROP TABLE yourTable
ALTER TABLE yourNewTable RENAME TO yourTable
```

Comment: That's it.  Thanks Tim.  I was staring at it too long and was tunneled on adding an update.  Better to just pull and tally the results and stick them in a temp table, then overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Only update the email with more clicks.

```
UPDATE yourTable a 
JOIN (SELECT email, 
             MAX(clicks) as m_clicks, 
             SUM(clicks) as s_clicks
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY email) b
  ON a.email = b.email
 AND a.clicks = b.m_clicks
SET a.clicks = b.s_clicks;
```

Then `DELETE`

```
DELETE yourTable a
LEFT JOIN   yourTable b
       ON   a.clicks > b.clicks
WHERE b.clicks is NOT NULL
```

**EDIT**:

I just realize you can have two rows with same number of clicks. That is why you should always have one `ID` columns to work as `PK`.

So you can add to eliminate any duplicates.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE yourTable
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_clicks (email, clicks);
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the answer I gave.

Answer (score 0):

You may use aggregate function sum() and group by.

```
SELECT email, sum(clicks) as sum FROM tableName group by email
```

Comment: how is this different to Tim Answer?

Comment: I saw the other answer only after posting this.